# Media (video) negotiation in Astrisk

Tags: asterisk

First, let me dictate the call flow and the nodes involved.

*UA1 <--------------> Proxy1 (Kamailio)/RTPProxy1 <-------------------> **Asterisk** <-------------> Proxy2(Kamailio) /RTPProxy2<---------> UA2*

Currently, Asterisk acts as a B2BUA server, and the location lookup/registration is handled by the Proxies. The Asterisk is in the signaling as well as media (audio) path.

Problem Statement:

Asterisk should be in the audio path and not video path if the call is an audio+video call. So, audio goes from UA1 to RTPproxy, Asterisk to RTPProxy to UA2 and back. While video from UA1 to RTPProxy 1 to RTProxy2 to UA2.
Question:

Can Asterisk be configured/programmed, so that it negotiates with RTPProxy1/2 video IP/port? While for Audio it does negotiation with its own IP and Port as its currently doing.
Thanks
Abhijit

Answer (score 0):

No, asterisk video is very limited. Negotiation options are same, so it will work same as audio.

If you want make it different, create TWO calls - one audio call and one video call without audio.

However if you use kamailio as proxy, in theory it is POSSIBLE make it like you want. But very unlikly your UA will support that(at least i never hear about something like that).